# Power Bi Dax, Calculate different level of Wtg average

Tags: powerbi, dax

i got below Dax in expression , once i put this in a column i get wrong values.

```
L3_final score = 
DIVIDE(
    SUMX(
       'AIA Structure_level_wtg',
       'AIA Structure_level_wtg'[L3 Wtg]
           * AVERAGE('AIA Structure_level_wtg'[Infra_l3_finalScore])
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('AIA Structure_level_wtg'[L3 Wtg]), 
        'AIA Structure_level_wtg'[Infra_l3_finalScore] > 0
    ),
    0
)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check each part of DIVIDE? Which value is wrong first o second?

Comment: It is because of that AVERAGE() function. Do you need it really there?

Comment: Don't put it into a calculated column, put it into a measure instead. You don't need row context here.

Comment: "Multiple expression" sounds good ...

Comment: @ Ozan Sen, i am using  this column as a reference to store the value from the expression Infra_l3_finalScore hence the average score, can i use the Expression directly in  its place?

Comment: So i am doing below to calculate the different score at difference level based on their Weightings

Comment: L3_final score = 
DIVIDE(
    SUMX(
       'AIA Structure_level_wtg',
        'AIA Structure_level_wtg'[L3 Wtg]* AVERAGE('AIA Structure_level_wtg'[Infra_l3_finalScore])
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('AIA Structure_level_wtg'[L3 Wtg]), 'AIA Structure_level_wtg'[Infra_l3_finalScore]>0
    ),0
)

Comment: L2_final score = 
DIVIDE(
    SUMX(
       'AIA Structure_level_wtg',
        'AIA Structure_level_wtg'[L2 Wtg.]* [L3_final score]
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('AIA Structure_level_wtg'[L2 Wtg.])
    ),0
)

Comment: L1_final score = 
DIVIDE(
    SUMX(
       'AIA Structure_level_wtg',
        'AIA Structure_level_wtg'[L1 Wtg.]* [L2_final score]
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('AIA Structure_level_wtg'[L1 Wtg.])
    ),0
)

Comment: saved the sample data in original post

Comment: Where is [Infra_l3_finalScore] column on the file? What It stands for?

Comment: its is score for individual item score in a grp, which is in fact a expression but to bring in to another table which holds all weightings i have stored in a column